Deployment Error: Laravel Project Fails to Build on Vercel
hello everyone I deployed laravel project on vercel but as you see the style does not work
here is the vercel.json file
{
    "version": 2,
    "framework": null,
    "functions": {
        "api/index.php": { "runtime": "vercel-php@0.6.2" }
    },
    "routes": [{
        "src": "/(.*)",
        "dest": "/api/index.php"
    }],
    "env": {
        "APP_ENV": "production",
        "APP_DEBUG": "true",
        "APP_URL": "https://monprojetrpr-kknyyqxg1-mon-preojets-projects.vercel.app",
        "APP_KEY":"base64:NkFCaaIosqoGqzaKnurnBbQJBCX1MX31uqalMo3ZtcM=",
 
        "APP_CONFIG_CACHE": "/tmp/config.php",
        "APP_EVENTS_CACHE": "/tmp/events.php",
        "APP_PACKAGES_CACHE": "/tmp/packages.php",
        "APP_ROUTES_CACHE": "/tmp/routes.php",
        "APP_SERVICES_CACHE": "/tmp/services.php",
        "VIEW_COMPILED_PATH": "/tmp",
 
        "CACHE_DRIVER": "array",
        "LOG_CHANNEL": "stderr",
        "SESSION_DRIVER": "cookie"
    }
}

